# How Acid test are created?

Tags: language-agnostic

How Acid test can be created if there is no compatible browser to test?

And they ensure credibility?

(http://acid3.acidtests.org/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You design a page that has various elements that conform to the standard.  You test it in a browser that you think conforms to the standard (or at least comes close).  Over time you correct your test as errors are found so that it more accurately reflects the standard.  At least initially -- assuming browsers aren't very close -- you have to rely on a lot of hand inspection.  As browsers get better and better, you can rely on the performance of the browser as you make changes to make sure you aren't introducing errors.

You might find the [Director's Comments](http://ln.hixie.ch/?start=1208832542&order=1&count=5) blog useful in understanding how both the Web Standard's Project and browser manufacturers are involved in ensuring the accuracy of the test.  There is also a Wikipedia entry that gives more detail on how the test was developed, [this one is for ACID3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acid3).